# MSDTC is unavailable, but only in one direction?

Tags: windows-server-2012, windows-server-2012-r2, msdtc

I have DTC enabled on 2 servers - a web server, and a database server.  There are a few places in our web applications where we need to use DTC (via a TransactionScope) to manage transactions involving multiple databases.  On our AD servers it is working fine, but for some reason it isn't completely working on one pair that are not members of a domain.  I get the following error:

```
 MSDTC on server 'DATABASE-SERVER' is unavailable.
```

Using DTCPing from my web server, I get a successful test, but from my database server I do not (it stops after the RPC call with no messages).

Some notes on configuration:

- Firewalls are disabled on both servers
- DTC is configured the same on both (the Local DTC Properties have Network DTC Access et, allow remote clients/admin, allow inbound/outbound communication, enables all transaction types, and 'No Authentication Required'
- Using DTCPing, I can connect from the web server to the database server, but not vice versa
- RCPPing works fine in both directions
- DTC is running on both
- I've restarted the service, and performed an uninstall/install multiple times on both servers
- nbtstat -c correctly shows the remote server names

The only difference between the servers I can find is that when I initiate DTCPing from the database server, it doesn't finish the test (it just says "Please start PING from WEB-SERVER to complete the test"), while if I initiate from the web server it complete the entire thing on both ends.

Comment: This is almost the exact same issue as a [question that was asked on stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14780514/msdtc-dtcping-works-in-only-one-direction).  It seemed more appropriate for serverfault though.